# Change IP address using VBS on Windows XP

Tags: vbscript

Want to configure IP part using VB Script. I got below script which will get the user input and change the IP address accordingly but it is altering only the IP address ,Subnet, Gateway along with this I want to add preferred and Alternate DNS servers.

```
Option Explicit 'Enforce strict naming
Dim WSH, FSO
Dim objComputer, objWMIService, objOperatingSystem, objNetAdapter
Dim strTitle, strVersion, strThisPC, strComputername, strCompNameRegPath, strWorkgroup
Dim strCCS, strTcpipParamsRegPath, strIPAddress, strSubnetMask, strGateway,         strGatewayMetric
Dim colMEM, colNetAdapters, colOperatingSystems
Dim errEnable, errGateways

'Setup scripting environment
Set WSH = CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Set Version info
strVersion = "v04"

'Set target PC for WMI
strThisPC = "."

'Set the Title for any dialogs
strTitle = "XP Clone Changer " & strVersion

'------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Section 1 - Use WMI to change IP address, subnet mask and gateway
WSH.Popup "Preparing to change IP address, subnet mask and gateway... Please wait.",2,             strTitle 'Inform user

'Setup WMI
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strThisPC & "\root\cimv2")

'Set specific WMI query so 1394 adapter is excluded
Set colNetAdapters = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled=TRUE")

'Get user input into an array
strIPAddress = Array(InputBox("Enter the new IP address"))
strSubnetMask = Array(InputBox("Enter the new Subnet mask"))
strGateway = Array(InputBox("Enter the new Gateway address"))

'Inform user
WSH.Popup "Please be patient whilst changes are made. This could take 10 seconds or     more.",3, strTitle 'Inform user
strGatewayMetric = Array(1)

'Make the changes
For Each objNetAdapter in colNetAdapters
errEnable = objNetAdapter.EnableStatic(strIPAddress, strSubnetMask)
errGateways = objNetAdapter.SetGateways(strGateway, strGatewaymetric)
If errEnable = 0 Then
    WSH.Popup "The IP address has been changed.",2,strTitle 'Inform user of success
Else
    WSH.Popup "The IP address could not be changed automatically." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &_
     "This may be because the PC/Laptop is not connected to an active network." &     vbCrLf & vbCrLf &_
     "Please check the IP settings manually afterwards.",2,strTitle 'Inform user of         failure
End If
Next

Set WSH = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
Set objWMIService = Nothing
Set colNetAdapters = Nothing
Set colMEM = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS servers can be set using the [`SetDNSServerSearchOrder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393295) method:

```
arrDNSServers = Array("192.168.23.13", "192.168.23.14")
errDNS = objNetAdapter.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(arrDNSServers)
```

If want the user to specify the name servers you could do something like this:

```
arrDNSServers = Split(InputBox("Enter the name servers (separated by spaces)"))
```

Enter the name servers separated by spaces (e.g. `192.168.23.13 192.168.23.14`). The string will automatically be converted into an array with the addresses.

Comment: @Ansgat Wiechers - But dont want to hard code the DNS values in scrypt it should be entered by the user in the pop up box

Comment: The above is just an example. What's preventing you from prompting the user for name servers the same way you're promping im for the other information?

Comment: I try ed to embed the code but it is not working somewhere iam doing mistake

Comment: Im Stuck with embedding the DNS code in above scrypt. how to get user input in to array for dns like above

Comment: `Split()` produces an array from the string returned by the `InputBox`.

Comment: No. Integrating the solution with your existing code is your job.