# Automate Changing (Possibly) Multiple DNS Servers

Tags: scripting, vbscript, dns

I have a script which utilizes VBScript to identify the DNS for the machine it runs on. I have it alerting me if the DNS I'm looking for is being used. My hope is to take this one step further and if that specified DNS is found, to change that specific one to another DNS. I've found some scripts which seem the basic idea, but I do not think they will replace the identified one, just the one that is at the top of the list.

Here is my VBScript which identifies specified DNS:

```
'Bind to Shell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Read Servers NetbiosName
'strComputer = objShell.RegRead("HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName\ComputerName")

strComputer = "."
wscript.echo strComputer

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colNicConfigs = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
 ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")

For Each objNicConfig In colNicConfigs
    If Not IsNull(objNicConfig.DNSServerSearchOrder) Then
        For Each strDNSServer In objNicConfig.DNSServerSearchOrder
            if strDNSServer = "8.8.8.8" Then
                wscript.echo "Works!"
            End if
            wscript.echo strDNSServer
        Next
    End If
Next
```

To clarify, the part I need help with is where the script prints out "works". I would like that DNS in particular to be changed to another specified DNS.

Here is some code I also found that claims to change DNS, but I am afraid if I insert it there it will simply place change the DNS at the top of the list, not the DNS I had identified:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "netsh interface ip set address name=""Local Area Connection"" static " & strIPAddress & " " & strSubnetMask & " " & strGateway & " " & intGatewayMetric, 0, True
```

Let me know if I can clarify anything! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set DNS servers using the `SetDNSServerSearchOrder` method (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16649554/1630171) for an example). However, that method expects an array with all DNS servers you want to use, so you need to read the current DNS servers into an array, modify the address(es) you want to change, then call `SetDNSServerSearchOrder` with the modified array.

```
If Not IsNull(objNicConfig.DNSServerSearchOrder) Then
  dns = objNicConfig.DNSServerSearchOrder
  For i = 0 To UBound(dns)
    if dns(i) = "8.8.8.8" Then dns(i) = "4.4.4.4"
  Next
  objNicConfig.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(dns)
End If
```